# Java web app on Heroku runs but doesn't answer

Tags: java, heroku

I deployed an app with Spark framework on Heroku. It was built successfully on Heroku and the server started, but when I try to get a response from the server I receive HTTP 503 and I get the following H14 error in my logs:

```
2019-03-10T17:52:44.983359+00:00 heroku[servergossip.1]: Restarting
2019-03-10T17:52:45.299269+00:00 heroku[servergossip.1]: State changed from up to starting
2019-03-10T17:52:46.338372+00:00 heroku[servergossip.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-03-10T17:52:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-03-10T17:52:46.769383+00:00 heroku[servergossip.1]: Process exited with status 143
2019-03-10T17:52:48.416183+00:00 heroku[servergossip.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main --port 37274`
2019-03-10T17:52:49.054556+00:00 heroku[servergossip.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-03-10T17:52:51.513243+00:00 app[servergossip.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
...
2019-03-10T17:52:52.672327+00:00 app[servergossip.1]: INFO: Started ServerConnector@3ee6bd4d{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:37274}
2019-03-10T17:53:09.078587+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=POST path="/bot" host=servergossip.herokuapp.com request_id=45e0301a-3c82-495e-830d-2db0b0d1f9ef fwd="87.240.189.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My `Procfile` file:

```
servergossip: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main --port $PORT
```

Code from Spark example:

```
public class Main {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        port(getHerokuAssignedPort());

        get("/bot", (req, res) -> {
            return "hi";
        });
    }

    static int getHerokuAssignedPort() {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        if (processBuilder.environment().get("PORT") != null) {
            return Integer.parseInt(processBuilder.environment().get("PORT"));
        }
        return 4567;
    }

}
```

I used commands like `heroku:scale *someproject* = 1`, but nothing happens.
So what's the problem?

Comment: As you can see your service is started on `0.0.0.0:37274`. To what port on Heroku you are sending a request to connect to the server?

Comment: @vancleff, that's irrelevant. Heroku provides a port that the app must use via the `PORT` environment variable, but its routers route requests from standard ports 80 or 443 to the app. It's very unlikely that port 37274 would respond at all.

Comment: What does "but when i try to get response from server - nothing happens" mean? How are you trying to get a response? What does "nothing happens" mean? Does the request just time out? Does it return with a non-200 HTTP response code? Do you see anything in your logs?

Comment: @Chris, yep, it return non-200 code. When i try ty get response, server log create line: heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running"

Comment: @Chris, "nothing happens" mean that server return 503 code. I try to get the response from the Postman with some string. No, the request didn't time out.

Comment: @Кириллпушкин, that's not "nothing". In the future please include all of this information (which might help figure out the problem) instead of saying that "nothing" is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [`Procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-format) currently defines a process type called `servergossip`. That doesn't make much sense. Change it to a `web` process:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main --port $PORT
```